# Ruby 2.0.0: undefined method `insured?' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, boolean

I'm getting an undefined method error while using `insured?` to check if a value is true:

Code:

```
car_rental = 100
insured = true
extra_insurance_fee = 10
damages = 30

renter_payment = car_rental + (insured? ? extra_insurance_fee : damages)

puts renter_payment
```

Console output:

```
/Users/###/Desktop/test.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method `insured?' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: ruby "/Users/###/Desktop/test.rb"]
[dir: /Users/###/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `class Object; def insured?; end end`, and the error will go away.

Comment: You need to just use `insured`, not `insured?` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time you use the question mark is in method declarations.
Values that are of boolean type will never have a `?`.

```
(insured ? extra_insurance_fee : damages)
```

would be correct in your case.

An example

```
my_array = [1,2,3]

if my_array.empty?
  //do stuff
end
```

or

```
(my_array.empty? ? puts "nooooo" : puts my_array)
```